# eclipse android xml editor screwing up id's across multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have 2 seperate xml layout files. When i update the id or text in a view in the first layout, the second layout is mirroring it.

So change the id of an imageview in layout 1 to ivImage, and the imageview in layout 2 will cahnge its id to match.

How do I stop it!

edit:

I think it may have something to do with having copy/pasted some xml files because the layouts were already set up near how I needed it. So maybe eclipse is messing up thinking two views are the same view and updating both xml files? Ill try turning off auto-build and see what happens.

edit:
no such luck, turning off build automatically, and un-checking update references, neither of them help.

Comment: Did you try to restart your eclipse?

Comment: yes, and clean + build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a hackish work around, copy the entire xml file into notepad++ or some other prefered editor. Change all necessary id's. Now delte the entire contents of the xml file in eclipse (do not actually delete the file itself, just all the text), and then save. Now copy paster from notepad++ back into eclipse xml file and save.

problem fixed.